# the parameter width in nltk concordance

Tags: python, nltk

everyone. I am now learning nltk, and I am confused about the Text.concordance. What does the width do with the display things?
I thought that the width means the number of characters around the word you specify, so the larger the width, the longer the result. However, I got this

```
>>> text3.concordance("beginning", width=10, lines=5)
Displaying 5 of 5 matches:
n the beginning Go
nd the beginning o
t the beginning 
t the beginning 
nd the beginning o

>>> text3.concordance("beginning", width=13, lines=5)
Displaying 5 of 5 matches:
e beginning G
e beginning o
e beginning ,
e beginning .
e beginning o
```

The width is increased from 10 to 13 but the lengths of the output become shorter!

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!